# Converting Enum to a String Object for Java seamlessly

Tags: java, parsing, enums

I am shaky with parsing and handling text files. How do I convert my method signatures with enums to strings so I can read from a text file and parse effectively without wasting CPU resources? I currently have method signatures like this

```
public void createReservation(VehicleType v, String cName, long phoneNumber, String sDate, String eDate) throws Exception //right here
{
   //trouble with representing VehicleType v in my Reservation text file    
}
```

Reservation.txt file looks like this matching the signature Above

```
"COMPACT", "John Wick", 312 900 6001, "2019-02-09", "2019-02-14" 
"SUV", "Harvey Dent", 302 600 2001, "2019-02-11", "2019-02-15"
```

In my main class I have a parseVehicleLine method like this..

```
private void parseReservationLine(String str){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    sc.useDelimiter(",");

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        vehicleType = sc.next();//there is an error here because it is still an enum of Vehicle class
        String cName = sc.next();
        long phoneNumber = sc.nextLong();
        String Date = sc.next();
        String eDate = sc.next();
    }
    sc.close();
}

public abstract class Vehicle {

public enum VehicleType
{
    ECONOMY(18.00), PREMIUM(22.50), SUV(25.50);

    private double vehicleDailyCost;

    private VehicleType(double vehicleDailyCost)
    {
        this.vehicleDailyCost = vehicleDailyCost;
    }

    public double getVehicleDailyCost()
    {
        return vehicleDailyCost;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain how I could properly convert the VehicleType enum to a String without issues? Thanks!

Comment: `v.name()` or `v.toString()`

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the text file as String, so I think you need to convert String to VehicleType, not vice-versa as you mentioned.

You should be able to get enum from String using `valueOf()`:

```
vehicleType = VehicleType.valueOf(sc.next());
```